# How to convert from org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT to ml.linalg.VectorUDT

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am using Spark cluster 2.0 and I would like to convert a vector from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT` to `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT`.

```py
# Import LinearRegression class
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

# Define LinearRegression algorithm
lr = LinearRegression()

modelA = lr.fit(data, {lr.regParam:0.0})
```

**Error:**

> u'requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce.'

Any thoughts how would I do this conversion between vector types.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

In PySpark you'll need an or `map` over RDD. Let's use the first option. First a couple of imports:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
```

and a function:

```py
as_ml = udf(lambda v: v.asML() if v is not None else None, VectorUDT())
```

With example data:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors as MLLibVectors

df = sc.parallelize([
    (MLLibVectors.sparse(4, [0, 2], [1, -1]), ),
    (MLLibVectors.dense([1, 2, 3, 4]), )
]).toDF(["features"])

result = df.withColumn("features", as_ml("features"))
```

The result is

```
+--------------------+
|            features|
+--------------------+
|(4,[0,2],[1.0,-1.0])|
|   [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution, @zero323. Had the same issue and this works very well (why Spark is using two ML packages with the same class names escapes me, though; maybe historical reasons).